# How to merge dataframe with array timestamp and plot on the condition of an array?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a time series dataframe and an array as below

```
>> DataFrame
            datetime   value
...
0 2019-09-17 23:55:00  210.38
1 2019-09-17 23:56:00  210.50
2 2019-09-17 23:57:00  210.51
3 2019-09-17 23:58:00  210.40
4 2019-09-17 23:59:00  210.41
...
```

```
>>timestamp array
[Timestamp('2019-09-17 00:05:00'),
 Timestamp('2019-09-17 00:16:00'),
 Timestamp('2019-09-17 01:21:00'),
 Timestamp('2019-09-17 01:26:00'),
 Timestamp('2019-09-17 01:31:00'),
 Timestamp('2019-09-17 01:56:00'),
 Timestamp('2019-09-17 02:06:00'),
 Timestamp('2019-09-17 02:11:00'),
 Timestamp('2019-09-17 13:36:00'),
 Timestamp('2019-09-17 13:41:00'),
 Timestamp('2019-09-17 13:46:00'),
 Timestamp('2019-09-17 14:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2019-09-17 14:26:00')]
```

I would like to merge these two objects and with any rows have the value of 'datetime' which same as timestamp value in array, the value of new columns will equal 1, other equal 0.

Then, I want to plot the vertical dash line on graph or just a highlighted dot of value for each time in the array.

Please help! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need:

```
#if necessary
#df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'])

df['new'] = df['datetime'].isin(arr).astype(int)
```

Or:

```
df['new'] = np.where(df['datetime'].isin(arr), 1, 0)
```